# How to design 3x3 buttons in auto layout support all iPhone devices using Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout

I need one help to design 3x3 buttons in a view controller. It fits all iPhone devices like 4,5,6 and 6+. Any one guide me how to design it.

Comment: kindly attach some visual clue, for us to better understand your problem

Comment: Use `UICollectionViewController `

Comment: Clue means three rows three columns of buttons I want to display in a tab view controller.  these three rows and three columns are fit all screen sizes not stretched.

Answer (score 0):

Use `autolayout` in your `xib` or `storyboard`. Put 9 buttons lets say

- 123
- 456
- 789

Start to make alignments :

- 123 -> align top views to superview.
- 789 -> align bottom views to superview.
- 147 -> align left views to superview.
- 369 -> align right views to superview.
- And select all buttons and set to same width and same height then your are done!